# Class X has more than one default constructor & ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I understand what the errors correspond to... What i can't understand is they way it is appearing on my code.

error message : 
Error (active)  E0339   class "Point" has more than one default constructor

Error   C2512   'Line': no appropriate default constructor available

main.cpp

```cpp
    Point p1, p2;
    Line line(p1, p2);
    cout << "Point 1\n";
    line.set_point1();
    cout << "Point 2\n";
    line.set_point2();
    line.print();
```

source.cpp

```cpp
Point::Point() : x(0), y(0) { cout << "Point created\n"; }
Point::Point(double tx = 0, double ty = 0) : x(tx), y(ty) { cout << "Point created\n"; }
Point::Point(const Point& tobj) : x(tobj.x), y(tobj.y) { cout << "Point copied\n"; }
Point::~Point() { cout << "Point destroyed\n"; }
void Point::set_x() { cin >> x; }
void Point::set_y() { cin >> y; }
double Point::get_x() const { return x; }
double Point::get_y() const { return y; }
void Point::print() const { cout << "Point -- (" << x << " , " << y << ")\n"; }

Line::Line() { cout << "Line created\n"; }  //CLASS "POINT" HAS MORE THAN ONE DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
Line::Line(const Point& tp1, const Point& tp2) : p1(tp1), p2(tp2) { cout << "Line created\n"; } 
Line::Line(const Line& tobj) : p1(tobj.p1), p2(tobj.p2) { cout << "Line copied\n"; }
Line::~Line() { cout << "Line destroyed\n"; }
void Line::set_point1() { p1.set_x(); p1.set_y(); }
void Line::set_point2() { p2.set_x(); p2.set_y(); }
double Line::get_slope() { return ((p2.get_y() - p1.get_y()) / (p2.get_x() - p1.get_x())); }
void Line::print() { cout << "Point 1 ==  "; p1.print(); cout << "Point 2 ==  "; p2.print(); cout << "Slope == " << get_slope() << endl; }
```

header.h

```cpp
class Point
{
    double x, y;
public:
    Point();
    Point(double, double);
    Point(const Point&);
    ~Point();
    void set_x();
    void set_y();
    double get_x() const;
    double get_y() const;
    void print() const;
};

class Line
{
    Point p1, p2;
public:
    Line();
    Line(const Point&, const Point&);
    Line(const Line&);
    ~Line();
    void set_point1();
    void set_point2();
    double get_slope();
    void print();
};
```

When i remove the `Line::Line() { ... }` everything works flawlessly. The main problem is this :

1 - Why does this line trigger the error message for the POINT class.

2 - Why does it trigger " ... More than one default constructor "

3 - Why does it trigger " Ambiguous call to overloaded function "

I am trying to create the `Line` object without any parameters just like `Line line;`

Comment: Please add the whole error message and the body of the faulty functions. And removes the `.` and `...` that makes it impossible to copy/paste your code in a compiler.

Comment: `Point(double tx = 0, double ty = 0)` provides 2 default parameters - how is it different from the `Point()`  constructor?

Comment: @UnholySheep is right. In your `main.cpp` a call to `Point()` is not ambiguous because the declaration `Point(double, double)` does not have default parameters but in `source.cpp`, the constructor `Line()` see both `Point()` and `Point(double = 0, double = 0)`, hence the ambiguous overload.

Comment: @UnholySheep ah.... You wouldn't believe the amount of hours i have spent trying to figure it out because i was thinking something in the Line class was triggering it.... Thank you sir, apologies for taking your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a default constructor is a constructor that *can be* called with no arguments. This includes constructors that do not take any arguments or constructors that have all the arguments optional.

You have 2 default constructors here:

```
Point::Point()
Point::Point(double tx = 0, double ty = 0)
```

They are not only doing the same thing (since the first one sets the members to 0, as the second one), but they create an ambiguity. Simply remove the first constructor and your code should work as intended.

Comment: Default arguments are only allowed in the parameter lists of function declarations. Here the default is in the cpp file, weird

Comment: @MartinMorterol A function definition is a function declaration, so you can specify default arguments there. And you can add default arguments in subsequent declarations (see e.g., http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#4), so this code is "fine" (at least from a standard point of view).